# Comparing the data of two tables in the same database in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, redgate

I need to compare the two table data with in one database.match the data using some columns form table.

Stored this extra rows data into another table called "relationaldata".
while I am searched ,found some solutin.

But it's not working to me
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx

can any one help how to do this.
How compare two table data  with in one database using redgate(Tool)?

Comment: give some sample tables and queries, something you have worked on...

Comment: 1)http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx                      2)SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM
(SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION ALL  
select * from tableB) data
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING count(*)!=2

Comment: When i tried this it showing both data rows but i don't need that i want only compare data save this extra rows into new table      select * from tableA
minus
select * from tableB

Comment: Can Any one help me please this is urgent for me and can any one suggest  any tools for comapare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red Gate SQL Data Compare lets you map together two tables in the same database, provided the columns are compatible datatypes. You just put the same database in the source and target, then go to the Object Mapping tab, unmap the two tables, and map them together.

Data Compare used to use UNION ALL, but it was filling up tempdb, which is what will happen if the table has a high row count. It does all the "joins" on local hard disk now using a data cache.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply do you have any tutorial or video for this how to do? y i am asking because i don't have any idea on this tool just before i came  to know about this

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **Except**  clause in sql server

```
INSERT INTO tableC
(
   Col1
 , col2
 , col3
)

select Col1,col2,col3from tableA 
Except 
select  Col1,col2,col3 from tableB
```

Please refer for more information

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/07/sql-server-except-clause-in-sql-server-is-similar-to-minus-clause-in-oracle/

Hope this helps

Comment: Ya thank you i already tried this but my data is same but columns are different like infoID,EmpID like so while i am executing query it showing error.

Comment: Can you share exact query that you tried so that we can help you

Comment: While columns are different how to compare?